# Access AWS System Manager Parameter Store with labels in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, ssm, aws-parameter-store

For a single key, I have multiple values in history since parameter store maintains history.

sample cloudformation script:

```
Parameters: {
        "P1": {
            "Description": "parameter",
            "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>",
            "Default": "KEY_NAME:VERSION"
        }
}
```

I can perform the above operation which is keyname:version

I want to access the parameter with labels and not version.

How can this be done with this or some other method ?

Answer (score 1):

You [can't](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) use labels in this scenario:

> CloudFormation **does not support** using parameter **labels** or public parameters in dynamic references.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use macros you can solve. Using a macro you can invoke a lambda that gets the exact value that you want from the parameter store, then the transformation is performed in the template and captures the value you wanted.

For example here I take some environment variables that are stored in parameter store to write them in an ECS taskdefinition. My macro is MacroEnvVars

```
    Fn::Transform:
        Name: MacroEnvVars
        Parameters:
          Prefix: MSX
          Environment: !Ref Environment
          EnvVarsLocation: !Ref EnvVarsLocation
```

Then my macro return the template updated &  modified and the deploy is performed with the env vars from parameter store

Please check here [in aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html)